# expo publish command is returning 'Request failed with status code 404' error

Tags: javascript, react-native, deployment, expo, publish

I am trying to publish my expo app (running expo publish --release-channel test).
I get a 404 response.
I tried downgrading react version from 16.8.6 into 16.8.3 and creating a new expo account but also using the old one that the same command worked before.
expo version: 33.0.0.
expo cli version: 3.4.1.
react version: 16.8.6.
react native version 0.59.8.

Please find the images attached below for more details related to my environment.
Thank you

[Error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bchf8.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjzl9.png)

[app.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubP7Z.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to update expo-cli - you are using a version that is >2 years old and points to a no longer existing endpoint